# pix2pixHD error with own dataset

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to generate my own images using the pix2pixHD pre-trained model. [Github repo found here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD)

The images inside the dataset has to be in grayscale with no alpha channel. The images in the repo has a size of 16 bitPerSample and I have both images in size 8 and 16 bitsPerSample.

When I check both my images and the images in the repo using `sips -g all`. This is the outcome I get:

```
pixelWidth: 2048
pixelHeight: 1024
typeIdentifier: public.png
format: png
formatOptions: default
dpiWidth: 72.000
dpiHeight: 72.000
samplesPerPixel: 1
bitsPerSample: 16
hasAlpha: no
space: Gray
```

The strange thing is that it works with the images that has 8 bitPerSample.
This is the outcome I get:

Grayscale input
[image: grayscale]
Converted label map
[image: Input]
Final output
[image: output]

When I run `test.py` with 16 bitsPerSample images, it doesn't work.
This is the error it gives me:

```
model [Pix2PixHDModel] was created
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 26, in <module>
    for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 210, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 230, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 42, in _worker_loop
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 42, in <listcomp>
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/home/paperspace/Documents/pix2pixHD/data/aligned_dataset.py", line 41, in __getitem__
    label_tensor = transform_label(label) * 255.0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 309, in __mul__
    return self.mul(other)
TypeError: mul received an invalid combination of arguments - got (float), but expected one of:
 * (int value)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (float)
 * (torch.IntTensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (float)
```

I am new fairly to Tensorflow and I have never used pytorch before.

Any idea what this error mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long did this take to train?  Any chance it could be up and running in 14 hours with 1 Tesla k80 GPU?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think I can help you. 
I haven't checked the repository, but from the error trace the problem appears to be following:

You are performing a multiplication operation betweenn the output of `transform_label(label)` (presumably a tensor) and a scalar `255.0`. This is fine as long as both your scalar and your tensor are of the same `datatype`. From the error trace however, it looks as if the output of `transform_label()` is of data type `Int / Long`, while `255.0` is a float.

I suggest you try `255` or `int(255.0)` instead of `255.0`.

If this does not resolve your problem, let me know what data type the output of `transform_label()` is.